# How multiplication operators affect existence and regularity of the solutions of an elliptic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, elliptic-operators

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded open set.
Given $A \in C^\infty( \overline{\Omega},\mathbb{R}^{n\times n})$ and $f\in C^\infty(\overline{\Omega}, \mathbb{R})$ we can search for a *weak* solution $u:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ of the PDE

$$L(u)(x):= -\text{div} (A(x) \nabla u(x))= f(x) \quad \quad (1)$$

It can be proved that if $A(x)\geq cI  \quad \forall x \in \Omega$ and $c>0$ (the so called *ellipticity* condition, please correct me if I am wrong) , then $(1)$ admits a $unique$ solution $u \in H_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$. 
This is achieved, for example, exploiting the Lax-Milgram theorem thanks to the  ellipticity condition.
We also have regularity theorems as Schauder estimates that ensures that $u$ is smooth given  $f$  smooth. And the spectrum of $L$ is positive.

> What happens if we perturb the operator $L$ with a multiplication operator? How can we tune the proofs used in the unperturbed case in order to work?

i.e. consider the operator 
$\tilde{L}= L+M_V$ where 
$$M_V:L^{2}(\Omega)\to L^2(\Omega)=g\mapsto Vg$$
where $V\in C^\infty(\overline{\Omega}, \mathbb{R})$ 
Under which conditions can we ensure existence and regularity?

> How does the spectrum of $L$ change after such a perturbation?

I have tried to prove existence through Lax-Milgram, i.e. I tried to prove that the following bilinear form is coercive and bounded in $H_0^{1,2}$

$$B(u,\varphi) = \int_\Omega A(x)\nabla u(x)\cdot \nabla \varphi(x) + V(x) \varphi(x)dx $$
which is trivial if $V $ is bounded below  by a positive constant, but this condition seems too restrictive to me. I hope we can solve this pde in more generality.

Comment: You should be able to find this in a detailed book on elliptic PDE - for example chapter 8 of Gilbarg & Trudinger says quite a bit. The usual approach is using the Fredholm alternative, and I think existence and smooth regularity will always go through. Uniqueness, though, can sometimes fail - for example if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $L$ then obviously $V = - \lambda$ leads to $\bar L u = 0$ having multiple solutions.